# How can I write each line of a file into a new file in random order?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and have been struggling with this problem for a while. I would like to write a function which takes a set of BMP file names from a file called `FileNames.txt` and prints them out in random order in a newly generated file called `config_1.cfg`.

The file names in the `FileNames.txt` file look like this:

```
E1I11D0.bmp
E1I13D0.bmp
E1I15D0.bmp
E1I17D0.bmp
E1I19D0.bmp
E1I1D0.bmp
E1I21D0.bmp
```

I would like them to be written out in a new `config_1.cfg` file, which should look something like this:

```
#Filename: config_1.cfg
#Subject: 1

-PRESENT 1
[Back] "E1I11D0.bmp"
[Connect] 0 1

-CALIBRATION 1
[Connect] 0 2

-PRESENT 2
[Back] "E1I1D0.bmp"
[Connect] 0 3

-CALIBRATION 2
[Connect] 0 4

-PRESENT 3
[Back] "E1I19D0.bmp"
[Connect] 0 5
```

All the BMP file names in the `.txt` file need to be written out in random order. So far, I have tried generating the `.cfg` file like this:

```
import os
import random

curdir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('/Users/UserName/Folder')

index = 1
count = 1

# Create output .cfg file

outfile = open('config_1' + '.cfg', 'w')

outfile.write('# Filename: config_1' + '\n');
outfile.write('#Subject: 1' + '\n');

#Get the BMP file names from the .txt file

with open('FileNames.txt', 'r') as fin:
    fileId = list(fin)

random.shuffle(fileId)

for line in fileId:

    outfile.write('-PRESENT ' + str(index) + '\n')
    outfile.write('[Back] ' + str(fileId) + '.bmp' + '\r\n')
    outfile.write('[Connect] 0 ' + str(index + 1) + '\r\n\r\n')
    index += 1

# Add SHUTTERCALIBRATION after each instance of BMP file name being printed

caliblock = 1

for line in fileId:
    outfile.write('-CALIBRATION ' + str(index) + '\r\n')
    outfile.write('[Connect] 0 ' + str(index + 1) + '\r\n\r\n')
    index += 1
```

Except, when I run the code, I what I get in my .cfg is this:

```
# Filename: config_1
#Subject: 1
-PRESENT 1
[Back] ['E1_I1_3D0.bmp\r\n', 'E1_I1_5D0.bmp\r\n', 'E1_I1_D0.bmp\r\n',     'E1_I1_9D0.bmp\r\n', 'E1_I1_7D0.bmp\r\n', 'E1_I2_1D0.bmp\r\n',     'E1_I1_1D0.bmp\r\n'].bmp
[Connect] 0 2

-CALIBRATION 2
[Connect] 0 3

-CALIBRATION 2
[Connect] 0 3

-CALIBRATION 2
[Connect] 0 3

-CALIBRATION 2
[Connect] 0 3

-CALIBRATION 2
[Connect] 0 3

-CALIBRATION 2
[Connect] 0 3

-CALIBRATION 2
[Connect] 0 3

-PRESENT 2
[Back] ['E1_I1_3D0.bmp\r\n', 'E1_I1_5D0.bmp\r\n', 'E1_I1_D0.bmp\r\n',     'E1_I1_9D0.bmp\r\n', 'E1_I1_7D0.bmp\r\n', 'E1_I2_1D0.bmp\r\n',     'E1_I1_1D0.bmp\r\n'].bmp
[Connect] 0 3
```

Rather than each file name appearing once and being followed by a calibration, I get all of them printed at once and multiple calibrations under each.

I would really appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Comment: How many lines are in the input file? Can you read the entire file in memory without crashing your machine?

Comment: `outfile.write('[Back] ' + str(fileId) + '.bmp' + '\r\n')` change `fileId` to `line`

Comment: You should not provide `'\r\n'` line endings.  Python will convert `'\n'` to the correct line ending for your platform automatically unless you are writing in binary mode (you aren't).

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
import random

with open("FileNames.txt", "r") as f:
    fnames = f.read().split()
random.shuffle(fnames)

chunk_format = """
-PRESENT %s
[Back] "%s"
[Connect] 0 %s

-CALIBRATION %s
[Connect] 0 %s
"""

outname = "config_1.cfg"
with open(outname, "w") as f:
    f.write("#Filename: %s\n" % outname)
    f.write("Subject: 1\n")
    for i, fname in enumerate(fnames):
        nchunk = i + 1
        nconnect = 2 * i + 1
        f.write(chunk_format % (nchunk, fname, nconnect, nchunk, nconnect+1))
```

Comment: It may be more Pythonic to use `str.format` rather than the modulo operator.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code, while iterating through the array, you should display the current line, not the whole array.

```
for line in fileId:

    outfile.write('-PRESENT ' + str(index) + '\n')
    outfile.write('[Back] ' + str(fileId) + '.bmp' + '\r\n')
    ________________________________^ "fileId" should be "line"
    outfile.write('[Connect] 0 ' + str(index + 1) + '\r\n\r\n')
    index += 1
```

Comment: A little explanatory introduction would harm nobody =)

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected it now. Only problem is that instead of getting one instance of CALIBRATION printed out after each file name, I get 7 identical ones (same number as the filenames).

Comment: Figured it out! Just got rid of the second `for line in fileId`.